C# - Is there a way to find out the DSN driver type using ODBCConnection?
I've written a console application, which merely connects to a database based on a connection string it is given. This uses OdbcConnection and does not take into consideration the ODBC Driver type.
try
{
    connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=" + DSN);
    connection.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.WriteError(ex.Message);
}

Now I want to identify the DSN driver type here, so for example, is it for a MySQL database or if it is for a SQL database. I need to know the type before I can write a specific insert statement whereby I will be using the native date/time function in order to enter the current date and time into one of the columns. Is it possible to find out the ODBC DSN driver type or identify the type of database from using OdbcConnection or another class perhaps?

After opening the connection there might be something helpful in the connection.DataSource property.

Alternatively look at the connections driver or database property if they are more helpful to you.
